# How can I redirect to google after save button is clicked in my list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, development

I have a list and when i try to add a new item and save it it redirects me to the list but instead I want to redirect me to the Google.com

I have opened the `NewForm.aspx` in SharePoint Designer and looked for Save button or any url related to Save Button but I found nothing there.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can add Script Editor web part to the NewForm.aspx page. Then add custom JavaScript which will first remove the `onclick` event of the Save button and then add the `click` event to the same button with new redirection logic. Example code from [Custom redirect after creating a new Sharepoint Item](https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/custom-redirect-after-creating-a-new-sharepoint-item/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
    // change redirection behavior
        button.removeAttr("onclick");
        button.click(function() {
            var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
            var aspForm = $("form[name=aspnetForm]");
            var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
            var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
            var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "MyRedirectionDestination.aspx");

            if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
        });

});
```

Comment: I am getting the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined,` I have added `jquery-1.8.0` library

Answer (score 2):

A twist on Nadeem's answer for those who can't do Javascript

You can use the Source parameter in the URL to redirect to another page, by default it will point back to the AllItems View

You can use your own value:

```
.../NewForm.aspx?Source=www.google.com
```

Open your current NewForm, and inspect it yourself
it will look a bit garbled because all special characters are URLEncoded with **%xx** notation

**Now make up you own URL with source= and use that on a page where you want to link to the Form**

If you want to change the the New Item button on the View you do have to use JavaScript to change the `href` setting
Apart from that its just creating your own hyperlink on pages

Nadeems cool answer uses JavaScript to change that `Source=` setting

Comment: Danny, I cannot find any way to use my own value, where should I put `.../NewForm.aspx?Source=www.google.com` I have opened my `NewForm` with designer but I can't figure out where to put it

Comment: Not on the Form, only on **another** Page where you have full control over the HREF link **TO** the Form page

Comment: Danny I want to redirect me in the google and where should I change my URL to add source= I can't get your point

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it from `NewForm.aspx`. The reason is we do not have any control on the code that is saving item. So you can create a content editor web part for doing this.

1. Create a custom from using HTML
2. Save Item using **JSOM** or **REST API**
3. After saving the item, redirect to google.

You can take REST API help from my article!

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: do you provide any code sample because I am new to sharepoint?

Comment: I have added an REST API reference in my answer